# Django: user.save() not saving updates to extended from

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-database

I am making a bank transaction system and I want the user to withdraw and deposit the amount into their account. I made the balance field in an extended form as the default UserCreationForm does not have a balance field. See the code below:

views.py

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login-page')
def dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        withdrawAmount = request.POST.get('withdraw')
        depositAmount = request.POST.get('deposit')
        print(withdrawAmount, depositAmount)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        print(user)
        if withdrawAmount == None and depositAmount == None:
            return redirect('dashboard')
            messages.info(request, "Amount empty!")
        elif depositAmount == None:
            user.account.balance = user.account.balance - int(withdrawAmount)
            user.save()
        elif withdrawAmount == None:
            pass
    customer = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'bankapp/dashboard.html', {'customer': customer})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import User

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    balance = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, User
from .models import Account

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128, help_text='Input valid email')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('balance',)
```

The code works perfectly and gives no errors but the balance does not get updated in the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the proper object.

You are saving the `user` object but you have to save the `account` object, so you need to:

```
user.account.balance = user.account.balance - int(withdrawAmount)
user.account.save()
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I tried it and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. Could you mark the answer as valid to help other people find the solution to the same problem? thank you